# Using System.Reflection to determine ALL references

Tags: vb.net, reference, system.reflection

I am trying to determine every single reference inside a dll with `System.Reflection`. However, `GetReferencedAssemblies` only lists the ones in the "References" (visible in solution explorer).

I would like to determine references from within the code itself, such as an `imports` statement. Even things like if/then statements, try/catch, absolutely **everything**.

Is this possible to do using `System.Reflection`? If so, how?

I would definitely prefer to do this without p/invoke.

Thanks for the help!

This is in vb.net.

Comment: What do you mean?  `GetReferencedAssemblies` should return every assembly used by the DLL.

Comment: If the code uses something from System.IO, I want to be able to tell that it used something FROM System.IO, without them having added it as a reference. System.IO does not show up with `GetReferencedAssemblies` if it is not added as a reference, even if the code itself uses it.

Comment: You want to recurse through the tree of referenced assemblies, filtered to those that are reachable from the original assembly?  What if the something calls `Type.GetType()`?

Comment: Pretty much. If the code references it in any way, shape, or form (pardon the cliché), I want to know about it. What do you mean about `Type.GetType()`? Are you suggesting this as a viable solution, or as a problem?

Comment: As a problem.  `Type.GetType()` takes a string and returns a `Type` object.  What should happen if the assembly writes `Type.GetType(Console.ReadLine()).InvokeMember(...)`?

Comment: With the DLLs that this code will be used on, that is not going to be a problem so long as MY code knows that the dll's code uses the associated assembly for `Type.GetType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## EDIT

As described by your later comment, you only want the assemblies that your code uses directly.

`GetReferencedAssemblies` **will** do that.

---

<strike>As described by your comments, you're trying to solve the halting problem.</strike>

You cannot reliably do this without actually executing the original assembly (and using the profiling API to see what type it uses).

---

You could recursively call `GetReferencedAssemblies` on each reference and get the entire tree of indirect dependencies.

**EDIT**:

For example:

```
static IEnumerable<Assembly> (Assembly a) {
    return a.GetReferencedAssemblies()
            .Concat(a.GetReferencedAssemblies()
                     .SelectMany<Assembly, Assembly>(GetAllReferences)
            );
```

However, you can get false positives if one of the references uses an assembly in a code path that isn't reachable by the original assembly.  Due to interfaces and polymorphism, it can be very difficult to weed out such false positives.  If any of code in any reachable code path uses reflection, it is impossible by definition.

Comment: Sounds like a hassle. You would think they would have included something like a `GetAllAssemblies` method or something. With your recursion idea, the problem is that this would ONLY get the references for the referenced assemblies. I only want to deal with assemblies referenced directly within the dll itself, if that makes sense. This whole concept is rather confusing certainly...

Comment: I mean, I do not care about assemblies which are referenced within referenced assemblies. I only wish to derive assemblies from the dll itself.

Comment: Then `GetReferencedAssemblies` **will** do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/).

(If you are writing a tool to analyze an app that's a big task)

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing namespace names with assembly names.  System.IO is a namespace.  It actually appears in more than one assembly.  The System.IO.File class lives in mscorlib.dll, System.IO.FileSystemWatcher in system.dll, System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream in system.core.dll

GetReferencedAssemblies is accurate.

Play around with [Red Gate's Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) before writing this code.